# Django looping through 10 items of an array each time a button is pressed

Tags: python, django

I would like a page to start by showing 10 items, once a button is clicked, the next 10 items are shown and so on. Pressing the back button will show the previous 10 items. How would I got about doing this? The items are in an array. Each item is a queryset.

Current code:

```
{% for item in items %}
 #format item to be shown 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Post your code whatever you have done so far.. and your question seems to resemble pagination.. so need more information on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination to get your page as expected.
Have a look here at [Pagination from Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/)